Regex returns eslint and ts errors
There is a text file which has key-value pairs as content. The value can optionaly be quoted.
test="value"

Now I need to get the value of a specific keyof, which I do with this regex:
/test=(")?(.*)(?(1)\1|)/m

This is working: https://regex101.com/r/DBAqOx/1
But in the editor
const regex = new RegExp('^' + key + '=(")?(.*)(?(1)\1|)$', 'm')

I do get two errors for this codeline:
Parsing error: Octal escape sequences are not allowed. Use the syntax '\x01'. eslint
Octal escape sequences are not allowed. Use the syntax '\x01'. ts(1487)


Your regex is invalid in JS RegExp. It does not support conditional constructs. And \1 is defined with '\\1', not '\1'

On RegEx101 make sure you have ECMAScript (JavaScript) selected, it will then show you the error.

Alternative: const regex = new RegExp('^' + key + '=("?)(.*)\\1$', 'm') (regex101)

A minor typo, but worth explaining in an answer.  Because you are using a string literal with the RegExp() constructor, you would need to double escape the backreference as \\1:
const regex = new RegExp('^' + key + '=(")?(.*)(?(1)\\1|)$', 'm')

